# LAMP-based "cloud" hosts like Mosso/Rackspace Cloud Sites and Cartika HAL?

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-computing, lamp

next to Rackspace's Cloud Sites and Cartika's HAL, are there any other web hosts that run hosted sites on real app server and database clusters (this excludes MediaTemple) and support PHP/Perl and MySQL (this excludes GAE)?

Answer (score 1):

Try dreamhost. They support PHP/Perl, MySQL on a Debian-based LAMP stack.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some success with [Verio](http://www.verio.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out Logicworks for enterprise hosting solutiuons, www.logicworks.net.

Best,
Nick